# How to improve performance of MySQL group replication?

Tags: mysql, database, optimization, replication, mysql-5.7

In MySQL 5.7, there is a new feature called Group replication used for fault tolerant system.

[Group Replication Doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-replication-summary.html)

I implemented the group replication with 1 master and 3 slaves and it working fine. But i feel it little slow. Slow means query taking time in execution on master. It may be because of master waits for acknowledgement from slave or time in certification acceptance etc.

I know it may be broad question but if you guide some parameters related to group replication to improve the performance then it will be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: "Slow" meaning that the Slave is lagging?  "Slow" meaning that `SELECTs` on the Slave are sluggish?  More details, please.

Comment: @RickJames: Slow means query taking time in execution on master. It may be because of master waits for acknowledgement from slave or time in certification acceptance etc.

Comment: What is the network latency between Master and Slave?  Is that similar to the slowness on the Master?  If not, then please provide some details about a "slow" query.

Comment: not the particular query, all traffic seems slow in comparison of the queries executing on single master server. Network is good. traffic is also less.

Answer (score 0):

As you say, the Master *does* have to communicate with its Slave(s).  So, yes, that does slow down each *transaction*.

Each `COMMIT` is delayed by the coordination among the servers.  So, two things *might* be possible in your app:

- Fewer `COMMITs`; that is more statements in each transaction.  (But not too many.)
- More parallelism at the client, hence more transactions running in parallel.